# Change BackColor of ToolStripItem on Mouse Over

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

So I have a MenuStrip in C# which I am trying to do a darkish theme for, but when I press the button for the dropdown menu well....

[image]

Is there a way to make it go from white to another color? I can't seem to figure out a way to do it. This is probably my first time even customizing context menus.

Comment: Can you shared some of your code with us?

Comment: Forget my answer.  thought it was a button.  Seems like ToolStripItems are a little trickier. see here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72ac8ee7-6146-451a-9df5-5e819c332501/toolstrip-button-hover-color

Comment: I don't have any code at the moment, I have just been changing the colors through the properties menu but can't find a property which sets the color for this. :/

Comment: check out that article I posted.  seems like there is a project on codeproject that might do the trick or at least get you started.

Comment: Alright I found some override properties that achieved what I wanted. http://i.imgur.com/pVm5fh6.png

So now I have a problem where the left side of the dropdown option is white. >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` event. It's easy. Just do the following steps:

1. We have a form with these items: http://s3.picofile.com/file/8188577184/Capture.JPG
2. Choose that dark backcolor for ToolStripMenuItem. I choosed `black` color for `fileToolStripMenuItem` in my example.
3. Use this for `MouseHover` event:

   ```
   private void fileToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
           fileToolStripMenuItem.BackColor = Color.White;
           fileToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor =Color.Black;
   }
   ```
4. Use this for `MouseLeave` event:

   ```
   private void fileToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
           fileToolStripMenuItem.BackColor = Color.Black;
           fileToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.White;
   }
   ```